# formula for Tangent point of two arcs

Tags: circles

Please Help finding proper formula for Tangent point of two arcs.
[image]

1st arc R = .030; 2nd R = 0.015, need to get mathematical explanation on how to get (0.02494, 0.01333) point. Assume that starting point of the 1st arc is (0,0)

Comment: Please describe the problem more properly. Also specify what you yourself have tried.

Comment: I believe that the full question should be: I've got a circle arc, tangent to the $x$-axis at the origin with radius 0.30; I've got another circle arc, tangent to the line $y = 0.020, with radius 0.15, as shown in the diagram. The right-hand arc's center is far enough from the origin that at the point where the two meet, their tangent lines are identical. How can I determine (a) the location of the center of the second arc, and (b) (more important) the location of the joining-point? 

Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need to know : "the location of the joining-point", specifically a formula or a way of finding out that point.
ps: R1=.030; R2=.015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

My image is scaled up ($q=1000$). Tangent point: $P=(|EH|,|GH|)$

$|AG|=|AE|=30, |GC|=15, |CI|=20-15=5$

$CIJ$ and $AJE$ are similar $=> \frac{|AE|}{|AJ|}=\frac{|CI|}{|CJ|} => |CJ|=9$

$CIJ$ and $GHJ$ are similar $=> \frac{|GH|}{|GJ|}=\frac{|CI|}{|CJ|} => \underline{|GH|=13.333...}$

From Pythagoras theorem: $|EJ|=\sqrt{|AJ|^2-|AE|^2}=44.8998886413, |HJ|=\sqrt{|GJ|^2-|GH|^2}=19.9555060628$

$|EJ|-|HJ|=\underline{|EH|=24.9443825785}$

Comment: how did you find AJ?

Comment: |AJ|=|CJ|+|AG|+|GC|=|CJ|+45; (30)/(|CJ|+45)=(5)/(|CJ|) => 5*(|CJ|+45)=30*(|CJ|)

Comment: YOU ARE GENIUS!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. I will use $R_1$ for 0.03, $R_2$ for 0.015, and $h$ for $0.020$

Clearly the center of the two circles are
$$C_1=(0,R_1),~~ C_2=(c_x, h-R_2)$$
where $c_x$ is unknown.

Distance between the centers is
$$
\sqrt{c_x^2+(R_1+R_2-h)^2}$$
and for the two circles to have a common tangent, we need
$$
\sqrt{c_x^2+(R_1+R_2-h)^2} = R_1+R_2 ~~\Rightarrow~~c_x = \pm \sqrt{2\,h\,R2+2\,h\,R1-{h}^{2}}$$
From the figure we pick the positive root.

Now the line connecting the two points have to be divided in the ratio of $R_1:R_2$.
Hence the common point of contact is
$$
P = \frac{R_2 C_1 + R_1 C_2}{R_1+R_2} =\left(\frac{R_1 c_x}{R_1+R_2}, \frac{h R_1}{R_1+R_2}\right)$$

Now substitute the values to get the answer.

If this is a *homework* problem, you should show some work when you ask a question. Since you did not show any work, I decided to wait half an hour before answering!